# presentViewController won't go vertical

Tags: ios6

This code presents my new view controller, but it comes in from the right instead of up from the bottom. I can't figure out how to get it to do a vertical animation. Any thoughts?

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                            initWithRootViewController:newDeal];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it - my segue was set to "Push" and not "Modal". Once I set the style to Modal and the transition to "Cover Vertical" it worked perfectly.